# Difference between geocoder.setInput() and geocoder.query()?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

`MapboxGeocoder` provides `seInput` and `query` methods both of which can be used to set an initial address in the autocomplete dropdown. But the problem is both sets the input and fetch similar locations and show the results. Is it possible to just set the input value without showing the places suggestions list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the problem is both sets the input and fetch similar locations and show the results

Unlike query, which is used to "set & query the input", [setInput](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#setinput) only sets input.

```
var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
}); 

map.addControl(geocoder);

geocoder.setInput("New York");
```

Comment: `setInput`  triggered the place search and shows a dropdown with query results.

Comment: It's not supposed to work this way. If you take a look at https://anatolysukhanov.com/mapbox/stackoverflow/geocoder.html, you'll see it just sets the input text to "New York".

Comment: Thank you. But, I think it works only in old versions. I am using the latest version 4.7.0, and they have changed the `seInput` method to query the input string. Please find the commit [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/commit/a03e50243ebcfbc8f7bdb4465a2f556e073e6fed).

Comment: Ah, I see, You're completely right. It has changed either in 4.6.0 or 4.7.0. I opened an issue https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/issues/401 for that. Let's see what they reply. Whay can't you use 4.5.1 by the way?

Comment: Yeah, for now, I will just use 4.5.1